# Hover border position

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I have set bottom border the `ul`. On the hover over the items in the `ul`, I want to show the bottom border or the hover item exactly on the ul border. I'm unable to set the position of both borders (`ul` and the `ul` items) so that they go on each other on the hover.

I've tried using absolute position and the line height but could not get much success.

This is how I'd like:

[image]

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;     
}

a:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;    
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nNvfy/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to position both your `ul` and `li` - offset the bottom of the child `li` by the width of your border, whilst setting it to `transparent` then use the `li:hover` event/selector to set the broder color to red.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNvfy/42/)

Use the below CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    padding:10px 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-5px; /* <-- offset bottom of li by border width so it overlaps ul green border */
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; /* add border, make transparent so it doesnt 'jump' on hover */
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
li:hover {
    border-color:red; /* <-- use the li hover event (not a hover) to color the border */
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution in few second.

Comment: That's probably also how I would've done it, but I'm still wondering if there's a better solution (eg. without explicitly setting the height)

Comment: Awesome, I tried too but failed to make the red border visible over the green one. Perfect :)

Comment: really, you edited it to work just like the answer i posted a few minutes after i posted mine.

Comment: @labtoy - unintentional, I wasn't looking at the thread just replying to Tyblitz directly. Apologies for any offence, I'm not here for reputation (you stop even noticing it after a few k), indeed - after that change only one additional vote was made on this answer, and that was a downvote. Note the original answer works equally as well- and attracted the positive attention.

Comment: @SW4 yes, the downvote was from me, because you changed your code pretty dramatically. regardless, the question was answered and an answer accepted. no harm done.

Comment: @labtoy - I know its not recompense but +1 from me

Comment: Damn these ppl with high rep :D they are too fast, hard to compete with!

Answer (score 4):

here you go, working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/hKVp6/

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;   
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red; 
    margin-bottom: -5px; /* same as bottom border */    
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but here is a solution **without** negative values and using `positions`. Basically I used only `background colors`:

```
.box{
    background:green;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    background:white;
}

ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul li a{
    background:white;
}

li a:hover{
    border-bottom:5px solid red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNvfy/52)

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:
 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nNvfy/22/)**

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;   
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    z-index:999;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
ul li:hover {
    z-index:9999;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `5px` `transparent` `border` and make it `red` on `hover`. Try this code

```
<div class="box">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green; 
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;    
}

li:hover{    
   border-color: red;
}
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/nNvfy/47/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for your solution. Just don't set the border to the `ul`, but insert an `div`-element with a border. So you don't depend on the list.

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNvfy/37/)

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 500px
}
#border {
    width: 100%
    position: absoulte;
    margin-top: -15px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}
ul li:hover {
     border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;     
}
```